# Create an embed code to allow affiliate to display information from my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, embed

I am trying to create a script (jQuery) that I give to an affiliate partner which will allow them to display the contents of my DIV on their website.

I have seen this done before but cannot find any info on executing it. The user would put this in their website content:

```
<script src="https//:www.awebsite.com/123UniqueScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="123UniqueID"></div>
```

This would then embed something into their website and ONLY their website.

I tried putting this in the javascript file from google searches:

```
$('#123UniqueID').load('https//:www.awebsite.com #myDIV');
```

But this gives a `XMLHttpRequest error` on the affiliate site.

So how do I allow XMLHttpRequest for specific websites? And is this the best way to do this?

Comment: You need to setup CORS policy on your server to only allow access to the unique script _123UniqueScript.js_ from the one client (i.e. www.awebsite.com).  How this is achieved depends on the server you have.  There are lots of tutorials about setting up CORS on the web.

Answer (score 0):

#1 You'd need to set up a CORS policy that allows that other site to access your server resources. #2 You should just use the `<iframe>` tag, super easy:

```html
<iframe src="https//:www.awebsite.com#myDIV"></iframe>
```

Also, there's a space after your hashtag anchor and shouldn't be.

Read more about iframe [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP).

--- EDIT 23.3.14 ---

Whether it's an iframe or a JS script, that's a moot point. Either solution can be served exclusively to a single host or subnet by using a firewall rule. You could spin up a simple web server on a non-standard port and allow traffic only to your client's IP address. The other option is to dynamically generate HTML on your client's site by having them call a remote script, which is I think what you'd like to do.

In either case, you will need implement some form of access control. If that's the case, then I would recommend hosting a script on your web server and implementing a CORS policy that allows XSS for your client's IP address only.

Here's how I would accomplish this.

1. You supply a script to your client and supply them an API key to access your server.
2. The script accesses an API endpoint that delivers ready-to-render HTML via a fetch() request.
3. You create a CORS policy to allow your client's IP.  The endpoint verifies the API key.

You don't really need the key.  I guess it really depends on how secure you need / want to make this.

Here's an example of how you might implement this using a web worker:

```js
const HTML = `
<div>Some content</div>
`

export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        // TODO: Store in env
        const AUTH_HEADER = 'X-Auth-Token';
        const AUTH_KEY = 'a long random string';
        const AUTH_IP = '8.8.8.8';

        if (request.headers.get(AUTH_HEADER) !== AUTH_KEY) {
            // Incorrect key, reject request with Unauthorized code
            return new Response('Unauthorized.', {
                status: 403,
            });
        }

        const data = {
            html: HTML
        }

        return new Response(JSON.stringify(data), {
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': AUTH_IP,
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS',
                'Access-Control-Max-Age': '86400',
            },
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: What's to prevent other sites to use the same iFrame code?  While this might be 'super easy' it might not prevent being uniquely called from the one site only (which is the OP's objective)

Comment: So adding something like this to my .htaccess file will allow specific sites to access the iframe?

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://site2.com
</ifModule>

The issue I was thinking an iframe would have is the embedder will need to determine the box size. The content length might change over time and it would not be mobile responsive.

Comment: You wouldn't need a CORS allowance to use iframe that's why I suggested it

Comment: If you want to restrict who can see a website, you should use a firewall rule

Comment: How is the iframe responsive? The user will need to set pixel dimensions which will not be responsive. And if content gets longer than the users pixel height, there will be an ugly, scroll bar in the middle of the website. Wouldn't there be a better way to make it more seamless?

Comment: I updated my answer. And FYI, iframes can be responsive.